# calculate exposure time in days

Tags: r

I want to calculate exposure time (days) from INDX to DS,RE,SE whichever comes first. If all (DS,RE,SE) is NA then time to a fixed date (2015-01-01), should be calculated.

Data:

```
DF<-tibble::tribble(
  ~ID,        ~INDX,          ~DS,          ~RE,          ~SE,
   1L, "2001-01-01", "2002-02-02", "2003-03-03",           NA,
   2L, "2002-02-02",           NA, "2001-01-01", "2002-02-02",
   3L, "2003-03-03", "2009-09-09",           NA, "2010-10-10",
   4L, "2001-01-01",           NA,           NA,           NA
  )

DF%>%mutate_at(vars(2,3,4,5), as.Date)

# A tibble: 4 × 5
     ID INDX       DS         RE         SE        
  <int> <date>     <date>     <date>     <date>    
1     1 2001-01-01 2002-02-02 2003-03-03 NA        
2     2 2002-02-02 NA         2001-01-01 2002-02-02
3     3 2003-03-03 2009-09-09 NA         2010-10-10
4     4 2001-01-01 NA         NA         NA        
>
```

Desired output:

```
# A tibble: 4 × 6
     ID INDX       DS         RE         SE         TIME 
  <int> <date>     <date>     <date>     <date>     <int>
1     1 2001-01-01 2002-02-02 2003-03-03 NA           
2     2 2002-02-02 NA         2001-01-01 2002-02-02    
3     3 2003-03-03 2009-09-09 NA         2010-10-10    
4     4 2001-01-01 NA         NA         NA
```

Which is the easiest way?

Regards, H

Comment: What are the desired values inside the TIME column?

Comment: Exposure time in days

Comment: @hkolvs As suggested, it would help to fill in the `TIME` column for your example with actual numbers. What should the `TIME` be for row 2? Is it 397 or -397 days? Or 0 days? When you mention "whichever comes first" - does that mean the first date chronologically _after_ the `INDX` date? Or just the order of dates from `DS`, `RE`, and `SE`? Perhaps the dates are already in order?

Comment: It means the first date chronologically after INDX date. So the TIME should be 0 in row 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you could try the following. For convenience, conditions are put into a `case_when`. If all values are `NA` for `DS` through `SE`, then use you selected date and subtract the `INDX`. Otherwise, using `na.omit` to remove missing values gathered with `c_across`, select values in that row that exceed `INDX`.  Take the first result (the minimum if in chronological order), and subtract `INDX`.

```
library(tidyverse)

DF %>%
  mutate(across(.cols = !ID, as.Date)) %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(TIME = case_when(
    all(is.na(c_across(DS:SE))) ~ as.Date("2015-01-01") - INDX,
    TRUE ~ na.omit(c_across(DS:SE))[na.omit(c_across(DS:SE)) >= INDX][1] - INDX))
```

**Output**

```
     ID INDX       DS         RE         SE         TIME     
  <int> <date>     <date>     <date>     <date>     <drtn>   
1     1 2001-01-01 2002-02-02 2003-03-03 NA          397 days
2     2 2002-02-02 NA         2001-01-01 2002-02-02    0 days
3     3 2003-03-03 2009-09-09 NA         2010-10-10 2382 days
4     4 2001-01-01 NA         NA         NA         5113 days
```

Answer (score 0):

```
newDF <- DF%>%mutate_at(vars(2,3,4,5), as.Date)        

newDF %>%
  mutate(time2use=pmin(DS, RE, SE, na.rm=T)) %>%
  mutate(TIME = abs(INDX-time2use)) %>%
  mutate(TIME=ifelse(is.na(TIME), abs(INDX-as.Date("2015-01-01")), TIME)) %>%
  select(c(-6))

     ID INDX       DS         RE         SE          TIME
  <int> <date>     <date>     <date>     <date>     <dbl>
1     1 2001-01-01 2002-02-02 2003-03-03 NA           397
2     2 2002-02-02 NA         2001-01-01 2002-02-02   397
3     3 2003-03-03 2009-09-09 NA         2010-10-10  2382
4     4 2001-01-01 NA         NA         NA          5113
```

Answer (score 0):

An option to do it is by means of ifelse conditions like this:

```
DF$TIME <- ifelse(!is.na(DF$DS), as.Date(DF$DS) - as.Date(DF$INDX), 
                ifelse(!is.na(DF$RE), as.Date(DF$RE) - as.Date(DF$INDX),
                       ifelse(!is.na(DF$SE), as.Date(DF$SE) - as.Date(DF$INDX), as.Date("2015-01-01") - as.Date(DF$INDX))))
```

Output:

```
DF
# A tibble: 4 x 6
     ID INDX       DS         RE         SE          TIME
  <int> <chr>      <chr>      <chr>      <chr>      <dbl>
1     1 2001-01-01 2002-02-02 2003-03-03 NA           397
2     2 2002-02-02 NA         2001-01-01 2002-02-02  -397
3     3 2003-03-03 2009-09-09 NA         2010-10-10  2382
4     4 2001-01-01 NA         NA         NA          5113
```